# gfortran Error: Expected formal argument list in function definition at (1)

Tags: compilation, fortran, arguments, gfortran

I am getting the following error with gfortran compiler for a code written in f77. I am using -std=legacy to overcome incompatibility issues. However, gfortran is still producing the following error. I've tried several things but can't seem to get rid of it. Any definitive help is much appreciated. 
Here's the error message and what follows is the code producing the error. Thanks!

gfortran -ff2c -std=legacy -Ofast -C -o bin/ref_syn  erzsol3.f qbessel.f qfcoolr.f
qbessel.f:136.29:

```
  COMPLEX FUNCTION BESHS0*16(X, IFAIL)                              
                         1
```

Error: Expected formal argument list in function definition at (1)

```
      DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION BESFJ0(X)
C     BESSEL FUNCTION J0(X)
C
      DOUBLE PRECISION X
      DOUBLE PRECISION SRNAME
      DOUBLE PRECISION A, B, C, CX, G, SX, T2, T, TBPI, XBIG, XVSMAL, Y
      DOUBLE PRECISION DCOS, DSIN, DSQRT
C     ..
      DATA SRNAME /8H BESFJ0 /
      DATA XBIG,XVSMAL,TBPI/3.4D+15,3.2D-9,6.36619772367581343D-1/
C
      T = DABS(X)
C     ERROR 1 TEST
      IF (T.GT.XBIG) GO TO 60
C     X RANGE TEST
      IF (T.GT.8.0D0) GO TO 40
C     SMALL X
C      TEST FOR VERY SMALL X
      IF (T.GT.XVSMAL) GO TO 20
      BESFJ0 = 1.0D0
      GO TO 80
   20 T = 3.125D-2*T*T - 1.0D0
      T2 = 2.0D0*T
C
C
      A= +4.125321000000D-14
      B=T2*A -1.943834690000D-12
      C=T2*B-A +7.848696314000D-11
      A=T2*C-B  -2.679253530560D-9
      B=T2*A-C  +7.608163592419D-8
      C=T2*B-A  -1.761946907762D-6
      A=T2*C-B  +3.246032882101D-5
      B=T2*A-C  -4.606261662063D-4
      C=T2*B-A  +4.819180069468D-3
      A=T2*C-B  -3.489376941141D-2
      B=T2*A-C  +1.580671023321D-1
      C=T2*B-A  -3.700949938726D-1
      A=T2*C-B  +2.651786132033D-1
      B=T2*A-C  -8.723442352852D-3
      Y=T*B-A  +1.577279714749D-1
C
      BESFJ0 = Y
      GO TO 80
C
C     LARGE X
   40 G = T - 0.5D0/TBPI
      Y = DSQRT(TBPI/T)
      CX = DCOS(G)*Y
      SX = -DSIN(G)*Y*8.0D0/T
      T = 128.0D0/(T*T) - 1.0D0
C
C
      Y=  +9.99457276D-1+T*(  -5.36366929D-4+T*(  +6.13732440D-6+
     AT*(  -2.06823782D-7+T*(  +1.30451717D-8))))
C
      G=  -1.55551139D-2+T*(  +6.83314931D-5+T*(  -1.47708215D-6+
     AT*(  +7.10458046D-8+T*(  -5.81753275D-9+T*( +6.75219505D-10)))))
C
C
      BESFJ0 = Y*CX + G*SX
      GO TO 80
C
   60 WRITE(6,61) SRNAME
   61 FORMAT(1X,//,'ERROR IN ',A8)
      BESFJ0 = DSQRT(TBPI/T)
C
   80 RETURN
      END
      DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION BESFJ1(X)
C     BESSEL FUNCTION J1(X)
C
      DOUBLE PRECISION X
      DOUBLE PRECISION SRNAME
      DOUBLE PRECISION A, B, C, CX, G, SX, T2, T, TBPI, XBIG, XVSMAL, Y
      DOUBLE PRECISION DCOS, DSIN, DSQRT
      DATA SRNAME /8H BESFJ1 /
      DATA XVSMAL,XBIG,TBPI/3.2D-9,3.4D+15,6.36619772367581343D-1/
C
      T = DABS(X)
C     ERROR 1 TEST
      IF (T.GT.XBIG) GO TO 60
C     X RANGE TEST
      IF (T.GT.8.0D0) GO TO 40
C     SMALL X
      Y = 4.0D0
C      TEST FOR VERY SMALL X
      IF (T.LE.XVSMAL) GO TO 20
      T = 3.125D-2*T*T - 1.0D0
      T2 = 2.0D0*T
C
      A= -5.777404200000D-13
      B=T2*A +2.528123664000D-11
      C=T2*B-A -9.424212981600D-10
      A=T2*C-B  +2.949707007278D-8
      B=T2*A-C  -7.617587805400D-7
      C=T2*B-A  +1.588701923993D-5
      A=T2*C-B  -2.604443893486D-4
      B=T2*A-C  +3.240270182684D-3
      C=T2*B-A  -2.917552480615D-2
      A=T2*C-B  +1.777091172397D-1
      B=T2*A-C  -6.614439341345D-1
      C=T2*B-A  +1.287994098858D+0
      A=T2*C-B  -1.191801160541D+0
      Y=T*A-C  +6.483587706053D-1
C
C
   20 BESFJ1 = Y*X*0.125D0
      GO TO 80
C
C     LARGE X
   40 G = T - 1.5D0/TBPI
      Y = DSIGN(DSQRT(TBPI/T),X)
      CX = DCOS(G)*Y
      SX = -DSIN(G)*Y*8.0D0/T
      T = 128.0D0/(T*T) - 1.0D0
C
C
      Y=  +1.00090703D+0+T*(  +8.98804504D-4+T*(  -7.95959347D-6+
     AT*(  +2.47105358D-7+T*(  -1.49751260D-8))))
C
C
C
      G=  +4.67768740D-2+T*(  -9.62145905D-5+T*(  +1.82113970D-6+
     AT*(  -8.29018528D-8+T*(  +6.58335466D-9+T*( -7.49818190D-10)))))
C
C
      BESFJ1 = Y*CX + G*SX
      GO TO 80
C     ERROR 1 EXIT
   60 WRITE(6,61) SRNAME
   61 FORMAT(1X,//,'ERROR IN ',A8)
      BESFJ1 = DSQRT(TBPI/T)
C
   80 RETURN
      END
      COMPLEX FUNCTION BESHS0*16(X, IFAIL)
C     COMPLEX*16 BESHS0
C-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C     BESSEL FUNCTION HS0(X)
C
C                           COMPUTED USING CHEBYSHEV REPRESENTATION
C
C-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C
      DOUBLE PRECISION X
      INTEGER IFAIL
      DOUBLE PRECISION SRNAME
      DOUBLE PRECISION A, B, C, CX, G, SX, T2, T, TBPI, XBIG, XVSMAL, Y
      DOUBLE PRECISION DCOS, DSIN, DSQRT, P, Q, Z
      DATA SRNAME /8H BESHS0 /
      DATA XBIG,XVSMAL,TBPI/3.4D+15,3.2D-9,6.36619772367581343D-1/
C
      T = DABS(X)
C     ERROR 1 TEST
      IF (T.GT.XBIG) GO TO 60
      IFAIL = 0
C     X RANGE TEST
      IF (T.GT.8.0D0) GO TO 40
C     SMALL X
C      TEST FOR VERY SMALL X
      IF (T.GT.XVSMAL) GO TO 20
      BESFJ0 = 1.0D0
      GO TO 80
   20 T = 3.125D-2*T*T - 1.0D0
      T2 = 2.0D0*T
C
C
      A= +4.125321000000D-14
      B=T2*A -1.943834690000D-12
      C=T2*B-A +7.848696314000D-11
      A=T2*C-B  -2.679253530560D-9
      B=T2*A-C  +7.608163592419D-8
      C=T2*B-A  -1.761946907762D-6
      A=T2*C-B  +3.246032882101D-5
      B=T2*A-C  -4.606261662063D-4
      C=T2*B-A  +4.819180069468D-3
      A=T2*C-B  -3.489376941141D-2
      B=T2*A-C  +1.580671023321D-1
      C=T2*B-A  -3.700949938726D-1
      A=T2*C-B  +2.651786132033D-1
      B=T2*A-C  -8.723442352852D-3
      Y=T*B-A  +1.577279714749D-1
C
      BESHS0 = DCMPLX(Y,0.0D0)
      GO TO 80
C
C     LARGE X
   40 G = T - 0.5D0/TBPI
      Y = DSQRT(TBPI/T)
      CX = DCOS(G)*Y
      SX = DSIN(G)*Y
      Z = 128.0D0/(T*T) - 1.0D0
C
C
      P=  +9.99457276D-1+Z*(  -5.36366929D-4+Z*(  +6.13732440D-6+
     AZ*(  -2.06823782D-7+Z*(  +1.30451717D-8))))
C
C
      Q=  -1.55551139D-2+Z*(  +6.83314931D-5+Z*(  -1.47708215D-6+
     AZ*(  +7.10458046D-8+Z*(  -5.81753275D-9+Z*( +6.75219505D-10)))))
C
      Q = Q*8.0D0/T
C
      BESHS0 = DCMPLX(P,Q)*DCMPLX(CX,SX)
      GO TO 80
C
C     ERROR 1 EXIT
   60 WRITE(6,61) SRNAME
   61 FORMAT(1X,//,'ERROR IN ',A8)
      BESHS0 = DCMPLX(TBPI/T,0.0D0)
C
   80 RETURN
      END
```

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not correct Fortran, therefore not Fortran 77.

The correct syntax is most likely

```
COMPLEX*16 FUNCTION BESHS0(X, IFAIL)
```

which is also not standard Fortran 77 but should be accepted by most compilers.

BTW, Bessel functions are included in Fortran 2008 (not sure if this particular one).

Comment: Vladimir, I tried that before posting the question not realizing that I didn't have permission to create the executable in the designated bin folder. Indeed, it was the issue and now fixed. Thanks a lot!